# Files not getting saved in Azure blob using Spark in HDInsights cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

We've set up the HDInsights cluster on Azure with Blob as the storage for Hadoop. We tried uploading files to the Hadoop using hadoop CLI and the files were getting uploaded to the Azure Blob.

Command used to upload:

```
hadoop fs -put somefile /testlocation
```

However, when we tried using Spark to write files to the Hadoop, it was not getting uploaded to Azure Blob storage but to the disk of the VMs at the directory specified in the `hdfs-site.xml` for the datanode

Code used:

```
df1mparquet = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://hostname:8020/dataSet/parquet/")

df1mparquet .write.parquet("hdfs://hostname:8020/dataSet/newlocation/")
```

Strange behavior:

When we run:

```
hadoop fs -ls / => It lists the files from Azure Blob storage

hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hostname:8020/ => It lists the files from local storage
```

is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the value of `fs.defaultFS` in the `core-site.xml`.

Sounds like the default filesystem is blob storage.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html

Regarding Spark, if it's loading the same hadoop configs as the CLI, you shouldn't need to specify the namenode host/port, just use the file paths, and it'll also default to blob storage.

If you specify a full URI to a different filesystem, then it'll use that, but `hdfs://` should be different than the actual local `file://`

Comment: `fs.defaultFS` is pointed to `wasb`. What I meant by VMs is the directory directory specified in the `hdfs-site.xml`. So hadoop is working in hybrid mode using both disk and blob.

Comment: Okay, then yes, what you've shown is expected behavior.

Comment: It's defaulting to azure blob storage when I've copied the Hadoop config. Thanks